# How to ask Gradle if a specific input is not up-to-date

Tags: gradle

Is there a way in Gradle to do something like this?

```
task printIsSpecificInputUpToDate() {

    inputs.property("file1", file("file1.log"))
    inputs.property("file2", findProperty("file2.log"))
    outputs.file(file("file3.log"))

    // if one or more inputs is not up to date
    doLast {
        // find out if file1 is actually the input out of date
        // NOTE: pseudo-code!
        if (inputs.get("file1").isUpToDate()) {
            onlyProcessFile2()
        } else {
            processFile1AndFile2()
        }
    }
}
```

If there is not, does that indicate that Gradle think this would be a bad pattern?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such API (yet). You can only define ("build") the task inputs and outputs, but not query them later on or get their state. To get a final answer, you could ask at the GitHub repository of the Gradle project, whether such a feature exists and if not, if it is planned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for are [Incremental tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#incremental_tasks).
You need to define your own task class for this, but then you can query exactly for the changed files in your inputs:

```
@TaskAction
void execute(IncrementalTaskInputs inputs) {
    println inputs.incremental ? 'CHANGED inputs considered out of date'
                               : 'ALL inputs considered out of date'
    if (!inputs.incremental)
        project.delete(outputDir.listFiles())

    inputs.outOfDate { change ->
        println "out of date: ${change.file.name}"
        def targetFile = new File(outputDir, change.file.name)
        targetFile.text = change.file.text.reverse()
    }

    inputs.removed { change ->
        println "removed: ${change.file.name}"
        def targetFile = new File(outputDir, change.file.name)
        targetFile.delete()
    }
}
```